# Google Analytics returning many "undefined" events

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've got a fairly simple Tag Manager/Analytics set up (firing events on clicks/visibility) and it's working as expected for the tags I've set up myself. However when I check the Analytics page there are thousands of "undefined" tags.

I've had a look at all of the tags I created and none of them should be returning "undefined" as the category/action (the label is "(not set)")

All I need is for the undefined events to be ignored (or even better to stop firing) in Google Analytics, as it's getting in the way of the client analysing the data.

Any help is appreciated

EDIT:

As suggested, here's the only User-Defined variable on the Tag Manager:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZRe1.jpg

Here's an example of one of the tags:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JiTm.jpg

and here's a tag being fired in the preview mode:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPB4o.jpg

Comment: You need to provide more information on your setup, how you're triggering the events and what the GTM event tag looks like, etc.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you see in GA? Also, Event Value should be an integer, not a string ([source](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#eventValue)).

Answer (score 0):

May be some other (hardcoded) event returns 'undefined'? 
Try to check in Chrome using «Dev Tools», tab «Network», filter google analytics calls.

And I notice you send 'gtm.click' (string) in field 'Value' that must contain integer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was simply just due to a tag not having a category/action/label that had been paused a while ago, the Analytics timeframe was covering from before when this tag was paused, leading it to show the undefined tags.